# Doubling dynamically allocated memory in a function using loops and conditions C++

Tags: c++, function, pointers, new-operator, delete-operator

So I need to add already existing films to a Listfilms function that allocates the films dynamically, and if there is no more space we have to double the allocated memory. How do I use pointers and "new" and "delete" methods in C++ please? And another - remove a film from the ListFilms without deleting it?

```
void ListFilms(string Films[],int nbElements, int* p){
    for (int i=0; i<nbElements;i++){
        if (Films[i]> *p){

        }
    }
```

This is basically my start but I know it is wrong. Can someone help me with this?

Comment: Why are you working with C arrays instead of [`<vector>`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector), which does all the hard work of allocating memory as required for you? Explaining to you how to do it manually in almost-C serves little to no practical purpose. You would be going to a lot of effort to not-really-learn-C++ (where using `new` and `delete` should almost never be necessary).

Comment: @DevSolar there are many instructors that assign writing `homework::vector` to understand what `std::vector` is doing

Comment: I don't think learning how to use pointers, `new` and `delete` is reasonable for a question here, tbh. You're looking at an instructional course or an introductory book.

Comment: OK, apparently SO moderators have twitchy fingers. Let's repeat: Instructors that inflict "learning C first" and "reimplementing basic container logic" on their students are **bad** instructors, and doing quite some damage to the language and their classes. Using `new` and `delete` is almost always a sign of bad design. Restricting students to "learning the C way first" is, not only in my eyes, a sure indication that you should be looking for *a different instructor / course / book*.

Comment: @DevSolar Its my university course not some online course, and this was only a small part of the homework they really wanted us to use new and delete operators, I guess it’s to understand how heap memory works, nonetheless thank you for the comments.

Comment: Don't take this wrongly. It's just that I strongly agree with Kate Gregory that C++ courses should [stop teaching C](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=YnWhqhNdYyk) (or writing your own data containers, really). It's a school of thought that follows the way the older among us learned things back in the day -- C first, and then on to C++. Unfortunately it is a really inefficient way of learning C++, and most people get stuck halfway between the languages, which is a really unfortunate place to be because C++ can be *so* much easier.

Comment: I largely agree with DevSolar. Why start with the details, if you can learn the fun stuff first? And later down the road, the details should be taught by using more advanced examples (e.g. how to implement something, which is not already available in the standard containers).